# Frobenius normal form

Tags: tensor-products, invariant-theory

i would like to clarify everything about  Frobenius normal form,so please help me to  understand it  .as i read  from  wikipedia

In linear algebra, the Frobenius normal form, Turner binormal projective form or rational canonical form of a square matrix A is a canonical form for matrices that reflects the structure of the minimal polynomial of A and provides a means of detecting whether another matrix B is similar to A without extending the base field F
it is basic definition of  this term.also  we know that  two matrix are similar to each other,if  they satistfy   following form

In linear algebra, two n-by-n matrices A and B are called similar if

$B=P^{-1}* A *P$

for some invertible matrix $P$

so does it mean  we should find  such  matrix which has similar structure as  given mattrix and also   minimum polynomial?
so for example  we given matrix

```
 B=[3 4; 2 5]

B =

     3     4
     2     5
it's characteristic equation is 


poly(B)

ans =

     1    -8     7
```

or $a^2-8*a+7=(a-1)*(a-7)$

what should  i do next? as i understand from Wikipedia  ,suppose that characteristic equation is 
 $a^2-2*a+1=(a-1)^2$

so it means that first matrix should be such matrix whose  characteristic equation should be $a-1$ ?or we have

```
 A=[0 1;1 0]

A =

     0     1
     1     0
```

?
if this is case,then how many times should i take tensor or Kronecker product or  how many copy should i  do of given matrix?in copy i meant
$A_2=A_1$
$A_3=A_1$
and so on,then take product(tensor product of  all this matrix) ?
so as i understand because this is  second order polynomial,i should take  only two matrix?but what if  we can't  get such kind of form?for example like this we get  first time

$a^2-8*a+7=(a-1)*(a-7)$

what we should do in such  case?thanks very much,please help me to clarify  this things